# How do I tell if a dictionary key is an NSArray or Bool type

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary key called "content" that can either be an NSArray or a Bool value. How can I tell what kind of data type it is? The following code will crash the App if it isn't a Bool value.

```
   NSNumber *isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[result objectForKey: @"content"];
```

Comment: I think it's bad design if you don't know the type of the value for a key.

Comment: @duci9y not necessarily true at all.  What if you are using the same view controller for, say, loading JSON from different URLS, one that contains dictionaries, the other arrays?

Comment: @user1947561 Didn't quite catch that. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @duci9y sure.  If I want to fetch JSON, but use the same UITableViewController subclass (it has the refresh control, and the fancy custom views, etc.), I don't want to repeat the implementation.  So, when I fetch the JSON, if each object is an Array, I know that each tableview cell should have a disclosure indicator, that pushes to a new view.  If that array is a dictionary, the cell should have the value as a subtitle.  Example: https://github.com/SergioEstevao/SEJSONViewController

Comment: @user1947561 That's a JSON browser, an edge case. Your JSON should have a well defined structure and well defined types in all other cases.

Comment: @duci9y I have a photo browser in an app that grabs the url from a dictionary, if the photo has a name (from a certain section).  Otherwise, if it's pulling from x URL, there's just an array of URLs, so it uses that as the url.

Comment: Didn't get what you said, but I seriously believe data should be stored and retrieved in a structured manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id obj = [result objectForKey:@"content"];

if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // It's an array!
    NSArray *anArray = (NSArray *)obj; // Cast it as such from id.
}
else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    // It's a BOOL!
    BOOL aBool = [(NSNumber *)obj boolValue]; // Cast it as such from id.
}
```

Comment: @user1947561  Number can be anything not just BOOL, so this is incorrect 

[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0].boolValue returns you yes

Answer (score 0):

```
NSObject *obj = [dixtionary objectForKey:@"key"];
if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [isKindOfClass:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) method.

You can check it like:

```
if ([[result objectForKey: @"content"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
  // array
}
else
{
}
```